# Как заменить отрицательны элементы целочисленного массива на положительные Java?

Tags: java, массивы, int

```
invert([1,2,3,4,5]) == [-1,-2,-3,-4,-5]
invert([1,-2,3,-4,5]) == [-1,2,-3,4,-5]
invert([]) == []
```

Given a set of numbers, return the additive inverse of each. Each positive becomes negatives, and the negatives become positives.

Comment: а изменить надо в том же самом массиве или на выходе можно сделать новый массив?

Comment: желательно вернуть тот же

Comment: перебираете массив в цикле, каждый элемент умножаете на -1.

Comment: А в чём собственно проблема? Задача начального уровня на массивы и циклы.

Comment: ну так проблем и нет, я новичок)))

Answer (score 1):

1. Делаем цикл `for` по массиву
2. На каждой итерации берём элемент под индексом `i`, т.е. `arr[i]`.
3. Умножаем значение этого элемента на -1
4. Возвращаем это значение на то же самое место в массиве (по факту `arr[i] = arr[i] * -1`)
5. DONE

Comment: ах ,я пробовала через if?сейчас попробую через for, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
array[i] *= -1;
 }
return array;
```

Comment: Можно просто `array[i] = -array[i] ;`

Comment: как по мне, то лучше модуль использовать : Math.abs(). и по поводу того, что лучше менять в том же массиве - спорное утверждение. в идеальном мире это всегда не так. я бы сделал так return Arrays.stream(array).map(Math::abs).toArray();